# Compare string with basename

Tags: php, string

I want to find out if the end of the URL is, for example, `?vote`

Using `basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).PHP_EOL`, I thought I could compare this with a string of `'?vote'` , but its not working.

```
 $url = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).PHP_EOL;
 if (strcasecmp($url, "?vote") == 0)
  {
    echo "they match";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "they DO NOT match";
  }
```

Comment: Why not simply `isset($_GET['vote'])`?

Comment: The problem is that the url could end with "?death=123&vote=1&banana=alone" and it would still match...

Comment: @Robert Sure, but you'd need a really good reason to care for that difference. :)

Comment: @daidai [Zend_Controller_Request_Http](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.request.html) is designed to handle cases like this, give it a try, don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == 'vote')
{
    echo "they match";
}
else
{
    echo "they DO NOT match";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The access to your `?vote`, we call it a Query String, and with PHP you can access to it like this `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. So you don't need to use basename.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(isset($_GET['vote']))
...........................
```

Answer (score 0):

To figure out if the `vote` query parameter is set, use:

```
isset($_GET['vote'])
```

If you really care about the position of the parameter coming right after `?` (you should't), match the value against `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. How exactly depends on whether `vote` should have a value or not and whether other parameters should be allowed or not. URLs are defined so the order of parameters in the query really shouldn't make any difference to you though.

Comment: That's true. :) You could do some `preg_match`ing to avoid that. Alternatively, if `vote` is the *only* parameter allowed, that simplifies the problem to a number of easy solutions. But really, unless you have a really good reason to be concerned about the *position* of the parameter in the query string (and I really can't think of any), `$_GET['vote']` is the way to do it anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I think the question itself is very ambiguous.